# Creating dataset of images for image classification

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I want to create image classifier with Pandas and Scikit-Learn libs, but I want to have my own data of pictures?
Since now, I have used pandas columns for features and result, but how can i add images to pandas column (process it), so that i can use it in classification?

Can I just add my images to pandas, process them and use them in classifier, or I need to do something different?

I have my .py file saved in the same folder where I have my .jpg images, but i do not now how to read them.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

images = ['...list of my images...']
results = ['drvo','drvo','cvet','drvo','drvo','cvet','cvet'] 

df = pd.DataFrame({'Slike':images,
                   'Rezultat':results})

print(df)

features = df.iloc[:,:-1]
results = df.iloc[:,-1]

clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)
model = clf.fit(features, results)

prediction_result =  model.predict(features)
print(prediction_result)

accuracy_test = accuracy_score(results, prediction_result)
print(accuracy_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think sklearn and pandas alone can read images. I would suggest that you use numpy arrays to represent images. There are libraries such as `scikit-image` and `pillow` that you can use.

```
pip install scikit-image
```

Verify installation by:

```
>>> import skimage
>>> skimage.__version__
```

You can then get an image as a 3-D numpy array with:

`skimage.io.imread(fname)`

The first two dimensions are x and y coordinates (where [0,0] is in the top-left corner) and the third dimension has values of the colour channels. For an RGB image, there will be 3 values for each [x,y] corresponding to red, green and blue channels. For more information, see [skimage docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/).